# What is the most efficient way to create Exchange 2010 mailing list from plain text list of external email addresses?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I need to create a new mailing list in Exchange 2010 which would consist of about 50 external email addresses. I have the list of (external) email addresses in plain text format.

I have previously solved this task by manually creating an external contact for each email address and then adding those external contacts to a distribution group.

What would be the most efficient way to solve this task with Exchange 2010? 
Does EMS help here?

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a CSV, c:\distro.csv with 1 column called "PrimarySmtpAddress"
2. Make a distribution group called DistroGroup
3. Add the contacts to the group with this code

PowerShell Code:

```
import-csv c:\distro.csv | foreach {
    $contact = New-MailContact -Name $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -ExternalEmailAddress $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -OrganizationalUnit "Vendors" 
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -id DistroGroup -member $contact
}
```

c:\distro.csv:

```
PrimarySmtpAddress
jim@bob.com
joe@user.com
foo@bar.com
```

Comment: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'email@address.com'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-DistributionGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Add-DistributionGroupMember

Comment: Need to apply SP1 first?

Comment: Sorry my code was bad.  Edited code should work now.  I forgot that you need to add the email address as a contact with New-MailContact first and then pass that variable to Add-DistributionGroupMember as shown in the code example.

Answer (score 1):

You'll still be doing the same thing, but it's definitely a task that's made easier with a little powershell.

You can use [`New-MailContact`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124519.aspx) to batch-create the mail-enabled contact object, then pass a list of those new objects to [`New-DistributionGroup`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998856.aspx) as `-members`.